# Character encoding problem with HttpClient.PostAsync

Tags: c#, .net, post, dotnet-httpclient

We have a legacy web app which runs ok manually from within browsers. When I try to use the same web app from within code using http posts, I get some Turkish characters as ?.

I have the following code to make a http post:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(); //static readonly in real code

var content = new StringContent("id_6=some text with Turkish characters öçşığüÖÇŞİĞÜ", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-9"), "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).Result; //I know this is not a good way, I'll focus on it later
var responseInString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
File.WriteAllText("c:\\temp\\a.htm", responseInString);
```

The web app returns me a html with some input values, including those posted by my code. Those form values posted by my code and those calculated using my values have bad Turkish characters, whereas the hardcoded submit button with Turkish characters look alright.

The web app returns this html (truncated for simplicity) to my code:

```
<!-- BELOW IS THE HARDCODED FORM FIELD WITH TURKISH CHARS OK! DISPLAYED AS: Programı Çağır -->
<input type="submit" value="Program&#305; &Ccedil;a&#287;&#305;r" name="j_id_jsp_262293626_16"/>

<!-- IRRELEVANT HTML REMOVED -->

<!-- BELOW IS THE OUTPUT FORM FIELD WITH CHAR ş BAD! DISPLAYED AS: some text with Turkish characters öç???üÖÇ???Ü -->
<input type="text" value="some text with Turkish characters &ouml;&ccedil;???&uuml;&Ouml;&Ccedil;???&Uuml;" id="id_2" name="id_2"/>

<!-- BELOW IS THE INPUT FORM FIELD WITH CHAR ş BAD! -->
<input type="text" value="some text with Turkish characters &ouml;&ccedil;???&uuml;&Ouml;&Ccedil;???&Uuml;" id="id_6" name="id_6" />
```

Response headers look alright:
[image: Content headers from debug]

What can be wrong?

EDIT: A similar code posting to a [sample form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) works ok:

```
    static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestHttpClientForTurkish()
    {
        var data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"fname", "öçşığü" },
            {"lname", "ÖÇŞİĞÜ" }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
        var response = httpClient.PostAsync("https://www.w3schools.com/action_page.php", content).Result;

        var responseInString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Assert.IsTrue(responseInString.Contains("öçşığü") && responseInString.Contains("ÖÇŞİĞÜ"));
    }
```

Comment: `&Ccedil;`, `&Aring;` are the [entities](https://www.fileformat.info/format/w3c/htmlentity.htm)

Comment: `&#305;`, etc are html [codes](https://www.starr.net/is/type/htmlcodes.html). When html is rendered, these entities will be replaced with normal characters.

Comment: Looks like twice entitized text. You can look if the `content` properly encoded e.g. `string text = await content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: Btw, shown code and the output are not match. Can you show the reproducible example like exact code and exact part of the output? You may use blank Console app with `async Task Main` to be able to use `await` there. Please edit the question.

Comment: var responseInString = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov the problem is responseInString contains some wrong entities. Those  static entities returned by the server are good, but those returned depending on my posted values are wrong. Returned entities are displayed correct; the problem is they are returned wrong from the server.

Comment: @aepot unfortunately I cannot reproduce the problem with a sample form being posted to w3schools. It works good there. Our service is internal, I cannot share it with you. I'm not entitizing the form input somewhere in my code right? Where can be the problem?

Comment: @CaginUludamar possibly the problem is outside of the shown code. Add more logs to the service and debug it with the "bad" data obtained from logs. About `FormUrlEncodedContent` you need no specifying any encoding for it because URL-encoded content is in ASCII range and any other symbols are already encoded properly with [HTML Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).

Comment: Also `Assert.IsTrue` from the last code block seems to be always `false`. Maybe there should be `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: @aepot The code above is working. Assert command passes. You can try it for yourself. Regarding the service code, chrome succesfully sends and receives Turkish characters to the same service. So it is something with my code.

Comment: @LDS I couldn't use ReadAsStreamAsync(). I got lost inside streams, encodings and byte arrays. But I was able to try 

var s = "";
foreach(var datum in data) s += (s.Length > 0 ? "&" : "") + datum.Key + "=" + datum.Value;
var content = new StringContent(s, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-9"), "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).Result;

It corrected letter Ç but not letter ş.

Comment: var buffer = await response.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync();
var byteArray = buffer.ToArray();
var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

Comment: @LDS I tried your suggestion as var buffer = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result; and the server returns a similar response with a similar encoding problem: <input type="text" value="some text with Turkish characters &Aring;0&Atilde;0" id="id_2" name="id_2"/>. Using Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-9") does not make any difference.

Comment: @LDS I've also tried to read as stream with no luck: var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result; var responseInString =  new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd(); The problem seems to be with Content of the request. When I change it to new StringContent(s, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-9"), "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") I was able to correct one letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My findings:

1. FormUrlEncodedContent class does not support an Encoding parameter (hence does not handle Turkish characters ok), so I had to use StringContent
2. I had to use HttpUtility.UrlEncode to encode form values (and use ISO-8859-9 as encoding).

Here's the final code without any problems in Turkish characters in form fields:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(); //static readonly in real code
var iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-9");

var content = new StringContent("id_6="+
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode("some text with Turkish characters öçşığüÖÇŞİĞÜ", iso), iso, 
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).Result;//Using Result because I don't have a UI thread or the context is not ASP.NET
var responseInString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
File.WriteAllText("c:\\temp\\a.htm", responseInString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the bellow code

```js
public static async Task SendRequestAsync()
        {

            var data = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
            var key1 = "fname";

            var val1 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("öçşığü");
            data.Add(key1, val1);

            var key2 = "lname";

            var val2 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("ÖÇŞİĞÜ");
            data.Add(key2, val2);
            MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(fs, data);
            var barr = fs.ToArray();
            var client = new HttpClient
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.yourservicelocation.com")
                };

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));
            
                var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(barr);
                byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/bson");

                var result = await client.PostAsync(
                        "api/SomeData/Incoming", byteArrayContent);

                result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Our service returns the main page whatever I post using your code. I guess it does not support something sent by this code. I'll work a bit more on this.

Comment: you have to decode at api var val1 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("öçşığü"); other wise do not encode this . the whole object is encoded here

Comment: I cannot make any changes on the server side, I don't have its code. Please remember that the server side works ok with chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Neither worked with `Uri.EscapeDataString()` nor `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` when using HttpClient GET request so I've ended up with something like

```
string requestUri = uri
    .Replace("{", "%7B")
    .Replace("}", "%7D")
    .Replace("|", "%7C")
    .Replace("\\", "%5C")
    .Replace("^", "%5E")
    .Replace("~", "%7E")
    .Replace("[", "%5B")
    .Replace("]", "%5D")
    .Replace("`", "%60");
await client.GetAsync(requestUri).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

to replace the unsafe characters according to [RFC1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)

> Other characters are unsafe because
> gateways and other transport agents are known to sometimes modify
> such characters. These characters are "{", "}", "|", "", "^", "~",
> "[", "]", and "`".